# Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, http, html

Везде стоит utf8, в чём может быть проблема?

[image]

Comment: Все записи до этого были добавлены на другой кодировке

Answer (score 1):

исходники не смотрел но если всё действительно так, то когда скрипт сохраняет в бд, какимто образом не вызывается **mysql_set_charset**('utf8'); при каждом коннекте к бд нужно это вызывать (обратите вниамание, utf8 пишется без дефиса. насчет с дефисом неуверен). также ешё раз просмотреть все файлы на кодировку.

и не забыть  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> в заголовке страницы. 
Не будем устраивать холивар - везде UTF8.

Comment: если сервер отсылает заголовок кодировки, то браузеру пофиг на <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: покапался в коде, решил убрать  $update=htmlentities($update); и всё по русски начало писать!)) не пойму как тут htmlentities виноват)) может кто подскажет

Answer (score 0):

попробуй записать в .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

для базы данных выставь:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

и ещё все файлы сохраняй без BOM-a

Comment: У мну всё также! Всё без Бома, и в хтаккесс, также всё

Comment: ну тогда только с дёрганьем из базы проблема, иначе я без понятия

Comment: если напрямую в бд изменить то тогда по русски выводится, а если потом передовать с формы то тогда абракадабра

Comment: чего? можешь пояснить принцип работы? яваскрипт добавляет кракозябру, или идёт перезагрузка и уже там проблема?

Comment: там идёт обращение с jquery 
вот посмотрите весь скрипт пожалуйста http://zalil.ru/32698223

Comment: в db.php убери header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); и добавь mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");  
вообще у тебя в sql.sql записи кракозябрами вставляются, пока больше посмотреть не могу, потому как на работе сижу и начальник палит

Comment: ок поменял всё, я и говорю в бд тоже такая же фигня записывается, ладно прийди с работы посмотри пожалуйста! буду очень благодарен

Comment: стукни в скайп full-polar-fox

Answer (score 0):

кроме кодировки в БД, нужно не забывать про настройки кодировки в браузере )))